# Python: nested loop mapping fields one by one

Tags: python

Python: 3.x

please help to resolve below nested loop by comparing number/name prefixes available in `datafile` by mapping them with `site_name` & `site_code` defined below.

`Code:`

```
datafile = [{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}, {'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}]

site_names = ('Site322', 'Site299')
site_codes = ('121', '24324')

afterFilter = []
for record in datafile:
    for Sname in site_names:
        if Sname in record['CallingPartition'] or Sname in record['CalledPartition']:
            afterFilter.append(record)
    for Scode in site_codes:
        if  Scode in record['CallingNumber'] or Scode in record['CalledNumber']:
            afterFilter.append(record)
print(afterFilter)
```

`Output`

```
    [
{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}, 
{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}, 
{'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}, 
{'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}
]
```

code executes fine, and i am able to filter the `dict` required by mapping the prefixes set in `site_name` & `site_code`.

i want to first check `site_code` mapping fields & append the result and if it is not matched i want to check `site_code` and append the `dicts` matched. But the problem is i dont know how to put this in if..else condition and i am getting repetitive output since each `dict` has matching `site_name` and matching `site_code`.

`expected output`

```
[
{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}, 
{'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}, 
]
```

Please help how to check with site_name mapping field, and if not matched, it needs to check site_code, hence append method is not repeated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of the problems is that you are checking each record for Sname and for Scode, so each record gets added indeed twice.
This solution keeps track of the result of each search and, if one has been successful, it does not search further.

```
datafile = [{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}, {'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}]

site_names = ('Site322', 'Site299')
site_codes = ('121', '24324')

afterFilter = []
for record in datafile:
    record_added = False
    for Sname in site_names:
        if Sname in record['CallingPartition'] or Sname in record['CalledPartition']:
            afterFilter.append(record)
            record_added = True
            break  # once a record has been added, there is no need to keep searching
    if record_added:  # if a record was added on the base of the Sname, no need to try other searches, so you can continue with the next record
        continue
    for Scode in site_codes:
        if  Scode in record['CallingNumber'] or Scode in record['CalledNumber']:
            afterFilter.append(record)
            record_added = True
            break  # once a record has been added, there is no need to keep searching

for item in afterFilter:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}
{'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}
```

An even better solution would be to define a function that looks for the tokens in the relevant fields and only adds the record once:

```
datafile = [{'CallingNumber': '+9198136551', 'CalledNumber': '121', 'CalledPartition': 'Site299', 'CallingPartition': ''}, {'CallingNumber': '24324', 'CalledNumber': '+919099640', 'CalledPartition': 'Site322', 'CallingPartition': 'Site326'}]

site_names = ('Site322', 'Site299')
site_codes = ('121', '24324')

afterFilter = []


def count_tokens(tokens, a_string):
    return sum(1 for token in tokens if token in a_string)


for record in datafile:
    if count_tokens(site_names, record['CallingPartition']) or\
            count_tokens(site_names, record['CalledPartition']) or\
            count_tokens(site_codes, record['CallingNumber']) or \
            count_tokens(site_codes, record['CalledNumber']):
        afterFilter.append(record)

for item in afterFilter:
    print(item)
```

Following the rule of evaluation of or, the functions are called in order until one becomes true, and not any further. In your example, because all the records are caught in the 'CallingPartition'  or in the 'CalledPartition' it would never go no to analyze the codes.

Comment: Hallo Marques.. this is perfect. i have found the second option useful and Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any testing, but it looks like its running the line:

```
afterFilter.append(record)
```

twice for each entry, causing it to double the output.
An easy way to fix this is just by checking if the record has already been added to the list:

```
if !record in afterFilter: #Check if the record is already in the list:
    afterFilter.append(record) #Add to the list if not.
```

If your list is going to be long (500+) look into using a different if statement.